Lehrer*Innen or LehrerInnen or "Lehrer und Lehrerinnen" in "formal" and "informal" context
If I want to refer to multiple male and female teachers, do I say "Lehrer*Innen" or "LehrerInnen". Or do I simply say "Lehrer und Lehrerinnen"? Which is the correct plural form, assuming it is being used in a formal context(when writing)?
Also does this apply to other words as well like "Student". Also what is the case for an informal context? Can I just use any of them(interchangeably)?

You can just use LuL

There is no clear answer to this. If you want to follow the rules of the Rechtschreibrat (body that prescribes language rules for public offices and schools) and want to gender, you can go with "Lehrerinnen und Lehrer".
(Language) conservatives argue that the traditional form, namely just using the basic form "Lehrer", is the best way to refer to people of  that profession without talking about gender at all. Feminists in the German-speaking world have rejected that notion for decades, saying that "Lehrer" can too easily be be misunderstood to mean only male teachers. They call this form the "generic masculinum" and imply that the fact that the male form is at the same time used as the general form is due to a patriarchic history of the language.
If you want to express solidarity with classic feminism, you can write "LehrerInnen", which was the goto form of the 1970s and 1980s on the progressive side of the political spectrum.
In parallel, the gerund form "Lehrende" also became popular. Other ways to avoid the gender form are to use alternative words like "Lehrpersonen" or "Lehrkräfte".
If you intend to express your solidarity with the LGBTQIA+ movement or if you write for contemporary progressive readers or readers in the academic sphere, you can go with the form "Lehrer*innen" (or "Lehrer_innen" or "Lehrer:innen"), which, although being used widely in these spheres, is also the most controversial form. It is rejected by majorities in every representative poll about it and has for now also been rejected by the Rechtschreibrat because of its use of non-alphabetic characters inside a word.
All of these forms can be used in formal and informal contexts, and people to whom gendering language is an important issue do use them in all contexts, too, because they see it as a moral imperative.
Otherwise, there is of course a tendency to be more "correct" in formal contexts than in informal ones, and the more of an effort correct gendering is, the more likely it is that shortcuts are used in informal contexts. One of the appeals of the shortened forms like "LehrerInnen" or "Lehrer*Innnen" for informal use is that they are easier to say than the full "Lehrerinnen und Lehrer".
I also know some teachers who use the spoken acronym "SuS" ("Ess-U-Ess") for "Schülerinnen und Schüler" in their daily internal lingo because they don't want to just say "Schüler", but also don't like the spoken form of "Schüler*Innen" with the glottal stop.

Thank you so much for your inputs. I would stick to using "Lehrerinnen und Lehrer", as stated by the rules of the Rechtschreibrat, when writing.

This answer unfortunately omits the most obvious and traditional wording which would simply be "Lehrer" using the generic masculine. Even if you might not like it, I think it should be mentioned.

This answer fails to mention that the Rechtschreibrat has actively rejected forms like "Lehrer*innen" (2023-12-15), instead it creates the impression that the approval may be coming soon.

@RalfFriedl So does this mean that the word is seen as inappropriate or incorrect on legal/formal documents? Also is this applicable in every german speaking nation and other german embassies/institutes around the world?

@tofro: I don't believe that we will ever just return to the "generic masculinum" in formal contexts at this point, I'm afraid that ship has sailed long ago. But, ok, I included it.

@RalfFriedl I know they have rejected it, but I actually do think that means nothing and they will give in eventually now that a whole generation of students has been brought up with this.

What does "classic feminism" and the "progressive side of the political spectrum" exactly mean? e.g. Clara Zetkin, Rosa Luxemburg, Frida Haugg, Helke Sander, just to name a few, weren't professed with word endings but with equal payment, equal treatment, reproductive rights, elective rights, and similar things.

@bakunin The era this refers to is literally in the same sentence, it's the post-pill post-1968 era of Alice Schwarzer and others. Please talk about that in your own answer if you have something to add, but this answer really cannot be a history of feminism or even of gendering in German language.

@HalvarF: I haven't asked you to write a "history of feminism" I asked you to define "classic" feminism and "progressive side of the political spectrum" - or, rather, how you use these terms. I wouldn't have called an author of the BILD-Zeitung "progressive" and I wouldn't have called an era "classic" when the movement in question was at that time already over a century in progress, but that is perhaps just me. Maybe the Axel Springer Verlag is indeed a leftist endeavour and BILD the vanguard of counter-culture.

@bakunin Wikipedia: "In Deutschland war bis Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts der Begriff „Frauenemanzipation“ weitaus geläufiger als Feminismus. Erst mit der Zweiten Frauenbewegung seit den 1970er-Jahren verbreitete sich der Begriff als positive Selbstbeschreibung für Angehörige der Bewegung Seit Ende der 1970er Jahre wird der Begriff „Feminismus“ häufiger verwendet als „Frauenemanzipation“"
"Bild" is a bastion of the conservative fight against "Gendern". Everything as expected there. I'm not a reader but I have no memory of them using the Binnen-I form in the last century, I would be surprised.

@bakunin We're completely on the same page if you're saying that feminism has much more important topics than Binnen-I forms, but OTOH it's a fact that the Binnen-I and the insistence on "making women visible" by overcoming the "generic masculinum" are inventions and demands of what we now call 2nd wave feminism.
